# Cocos2d fade in/out action to repeat forever

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, action, repeat

I'm trying to make a method for my `CCSprite` based `Player` class to start the player instance fading in and out until stopped by calling `stopAllActions.`

In my `Player` class I have:

```
- (void)pulse
{
    [self setOpacity:1.0];
    CCAction *fadeIn = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:0.5];
    CCAction *fadeOut = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:1.0];

    CCSequence *pulseSequence = [CCSequence actions:
                                 fadeIn, // I get a warning about incompatible pointer types...
                                 fadeOut, 
                                 nil];
    [self runAction:pulseSequence];
}
```

This doesn't work and doesn't address the repeat forever part.  I know I should probably use `CCRepeatForever` but I'm not seeing how to implement it correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have not run this, but I think others have succeeded with something like:

```
- (void)pulse
{
    [self setOpacity:1.0];
    CCFadeTo *fadeIn = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:127];
    CCFadeTo *fadeOut = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:255];

    CCSequence *pulseSequence = [CCSequence actionOne:fadeIn two:fadeOut];
    CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:pulseSequence];
    [self runAction:repeat];
}
```

Comment: I'm still gettting the incompatible pointer errors for both fade actions.  `~/Player.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types sending 'CCAction *' to parameter of type 'CCFiniteTimeAction *'
`

Comment: although if I change `CCAction` to `CCFiniteTimeAction` the error goes away and it works... why would that be?

Comment: I understand now, you typecasted to CCAction when you didn't have to. CCFadeTo inherits CCFiniteTimeAction. That is all CCSequence needs to know. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - works now too.  One more thing... the opacity property should be set to 255 in the first line if I want it fully visible, right?

Comment: Yes, it's the equivalent of 0xff

Comment: if for above pulse animation i want to increase or decrease animation speed dynamically on some action , how do to ?? Been searchin a lot , dint get an answer.got a deadline soon ! thnx

Comment: How do you change the duration of the above fade to dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it took me a loooong time to figure out why.

when you create CCSequences I found that you have to copy the CCAction.

In your case.

```
CCAction *fadeIn = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:0.5];
CCAction *fadeOut = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:1.0];

CCSequence *pulseSequence = [CCSequence actions:
                             [fadeIn copy], 
                             [fadeOut copy], 
                             nil];
```

Hope I helped.